# Is there an easier/quicker way to fully explore a planet for 100% completion?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I have 3 planets who are for 90% complete but even after hours of looking for that final species it seems impossible to find and it's driving me mad...

- Does anyone know if some animals only appear during the night?
- Is there perhaps an easier way of exploring a planet completely? It seems such a time-sink now looking for that final species...

Comment: From my own experience, I sometimes miss the flying species. Another thing that helps me is finding the buildings scattered around the planet that have the preserved specie that you can examine.

Comment: Done all of that, I think I almost killed every flying species on the planet to scan it, but always says its a duplicate of what I found. I hope it is not the same bug as with the technologies you discover which says it is duplicate as well but actually isn't...

Comment: Flying and aquatic creatures are easy to miss.

Comment: have you checked the underground for cave dwellers?

Comment: I have never seen anything of note in caves. Are there animals down there?

Comment: @C-dizzle so you are saying that the little scanning machines count as creature discoveries?

Comment: @garglblarg I have yet to see creatures in caves. There may also be very small creatures; on one planet, the last species I needed was actually a tiny floating weed looking thing.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf : well, i don't know if creatures actually live in caves or if they just fled in there because they were chased by some predator but i found some small rodent-ish looking creatures in caves on a planet with lots of animal life. so sure, it might be that they can be found on the surface. but i wouldn't be surprised if you need to go everywhere to find ALL the species.

Comment: @Reafexus I can confirm that sometimes animals do live in caves. I found a giant beetle like animal that was aggressive and could only be found underground.

Comment: @JasonHeine I'm pretty sure they do. Whenever I've scanned a plant or animal, then when I find them in the machine I can't interact with it because it's already been scanned in the wild.

Comment: @JasonHeine I went back and tested this on a new planet that I hadn't discovered yet. I thought the scan from the machines counted towards specie discovery, but it does not. It only helps your prestige with certain alien races.

Comment: @C-dizzle I had confirmed that last night, but you beat me to the response :) Thanks for looking as well!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Getting 100% completion on a planet is difficult. Throw a water planet in the mix, or a low fauna planet, and it becomes that much more difficult. From my playing experience, there are some things to keep in mind;

- Certain species do indeed only come out at night. On one planet, as soon as nighttime hit, I started noticing these weird pulsating plant things. They looked like that one Windows 2000/XP screensaver with the morphing spikeball.
- Creatures may be really, *really* tiny! Ranging from babies of certain species, to actual floating garden-weed looking things, species can be small. Keep your eyes peeled, and your Analysis Visor up.
- Aquatic and Flying creatures are easy to miss, as greg-449 pointed out. They can be tiny or large. For water-based species though, they tend to be large and easy to spot, or they stick in packs. They can easily be seen by using the Analysis Visor and looking for a pack of red dots. This indicates that you haven't scanned them yet, but I'll get to that later.
- For Flying creatures, don't be afraid to shoot them down. If you can find the body, you can still Analyze it.
- Use the Analysis Visor whenever you feel the time is right. This will tell you from a distance whether or not you have scanned a creature already. If you have, they will have a green dot on them. If you haven't, the dot will be red. As far as I can tell, using the Analysis Visor and scanning your surrounding area will also show white dots in the distance, indicating that animals are nearby. I play on PS4 on a 32 inch screen, and sometimes it can be difficult to tell what color the far away dot is, and it doesn't stick around forever. It is enough to point you in the right direction of potentially unscanned species, however.

Comment: Those tinier creature dots that fade away quickly actually don't even have a red or green color. They specifically represent "creatures that are too far away for your scanner to tell whether they're a new species or not".

Comment: @DanHenderson: Have you got a reference for that? In my experience you can actually get to point blank range on the white dots that pulse briefly and there is nothing obvious there...

Comment: @Chris I read it just the other day. I'll try to find it again and post a link.

Comment: @DanHenderson: There was a question on here with that answer but it also provided no evidence: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/282465/what-are-these-slowly-pulsing-white-dots-on-my-scanner

Comment: @Chris in my experience, it's true. If I get closer to white dots then they change colors.

Comment: @Kat: Interesting. Are you on PS or Steam out of interest? Just wondering if it could differ between platforms (would be weird but not impossible).

Comment: @Chris I'm on PS. I'll try to remember to take a video next time I play.

Answer (score 5):

Since patch 1.07 this no longer is possible. Planets without animals no longer have the 100% completion box and therefore no option to upload it.

---

> Is there perhaps an easier way of exploring a planet completely?

I spent a lot of time on my starting planet and the first I visited after that. Only to find out right afterwards that some planets do not have any species and you immediately can upload the 100% completion to update your milestones. From my experience these usually are moons.

Of course this does not give any Units for reward. But making money is much easier by farming resources anyway.

To upload the 100% completion and get the Journey Milestone updated, you need to hover the pointer over the box which shows "100%" and press <kbd>╳</kbd> (on PS4), not <kbd>▢</kbd>. That's the same when you want to upload the 100% for a planet which has species. You do not get the Units rewards automatically just by discovering all the `?????` entries.

[image]

<sup>Sorry, german screenshot...</sup>

Comment: How do you upload the 100% if there are no species? I haven't seen this option, or perhaps I just haven't moved the circle in the right spot.

Comment: @JasonHeine Yeah, that's not very obvious. You need to point on the box that shows the 100% and then press ╳. I updated my answer with a screenshot.

Comment: Danke :) Seems to be a bug after the 1st one uploaded. It won't do anymore after that. Thanks for this answer though. Quite helpful.

Comment: I don't think there are bugs in this game. I'm sure the foundation of the code is an algorithm that procedually generate 18 quintillion ways to annoy the player. The whole universe you see is just a result of it. :D

Comment: @udondan best NMS comment I've seen.

Comment: I really wish I'd seen this before they patched it!!