# What are these slowly pulsing white dots on my scanner?

Tags: no-mans-sky

[image]

These white dots pulse slowly on my scanner sometimes, on various planets.  They will show for about 1 second, then not show for a few.  I took the picture underground as at this particular moment there were a lot showing, but they also appear above ground as well.

I have tried to track them, they are usually a long way away. The only time I have been "successful" is when I found a structure of some sort, but I cannot be sure the dots actually mean "structure is here," as other times I have tried to track them and have seen nothing.

I'm starting to think that they are life-forms, but do not have enough data to corroborate.

Also, no, they are definitely NOT waypoints.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I think those are animals that are too far away to scan. Once they're close enough, the dots either become green (already scanned) or red (not yet scanned).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I just answered this as part of my answer here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/282464/91583), but I'll rework it for you, since your question is sufficiently different than the linked one.

When you use the Analysis Visor, it will show three things:

- Green Dots

These indicate creatures that you have already scanned.

- Red Dots

These indicate creatures that you have not yet scanned.

- White Dots

From my experience with the game so far, the white dots do indeed appear to be creatures. They only stay for a few seconds, presumably so that creature finding isn't an easy task, since the reward for 100% is so high. The game does not seem to be intuitive enough to tell you if you (from a distance) if you have scanned them or not. However, the closer you get to a dot, it will turn green or red depending on what you've done for that species.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on the white dots part because I believe I have seen them on planets with no fauna at all. But I might have been mistaken so I will do some testing later today.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer...and then experienced the white dots on a planet without any fauna. I think they might just denote places where animals are _expected_ to spawn, given certain criteria.

Comment: My white dots didn't disappear after a few seconds. I actually tracked down one of my white dots and it was on the corner of a mineral deposit on the top of a hill. There didn't seem to be anything special about it. It remained white even when I was only a short distance away from it. It was static and when I mined that part of the deposit nothing special happened and it just left the white dot floating in mid air.

So I am pretty sure this is not the correct answer.

Comment: @Chris The dots that don't disappear tend to be larger than the Analysis Visor's dots, and they indicate outposts, minerals, and the like, as far as I know.

Comment: @nailbones Similar to Chris, you may have seen larger white dots that lead to outposts, minerals and other things? Without confirmed information from Hello Games, it's hard to tell what it could be. :\

Comment: @Kaizerwolf: The ones I am talking about look exactly like the ones on the  screenshot. Have you got a screenshot of the larger dots you are talking about? I'm not sure I can think of what they would be...

Comment: @Chris I play on PS4, but I can try and get a screenshot to show the difference, and add it into my answer.

Comment: That'd be grand. I'm on PC (not sure whether that makes a difference) but I'll try to track down another of my dots and get screenshots next time I get a chance (hopefully tonight).

Comment: @Kaizerwolf No, they were not waypoints, I'm very certain of that.  If you find any on barren planets, you can get quite close and watch them pulse in and out of existence above the surface with nothing else around- _nothing else around_.

Comment: If you use the visor on e.g. a structure it will be marked and stay on your screen as a white dot with a circle, very similar to the animal ones, but I *think* the animals pulse.